# Highlight entire row if any cell is empty in excel

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have data from A:AD. I need to highlight the entire row into Gray even if any cell from A:AD is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   //Change this range 
Set MyPlage = Range("YourRange") //Change this range 

For Each Cell In MyPlage  

    Select Case Cell.Value  

     Case Is = "Withdrawn"  
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 7  

    Case Is = "Postponed"  
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8  

    Case Is = "Terms Agreed"  
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4  

    Case Is = "Papers Rec"  
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  

    Case Else  
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone  

    End Select  

Next  
End Sub
```

http://ccm.net/faq/8847-excel-vba-a-macro-to-change-the-color-of-a-row
http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm